# Delete file from second server via first server via php

Tags: php, file, delete-file

I have two servers. I want delete file from second server via first server!

For example:

- first-server.com
- second-server.com

I have made two php files - file on first server and file on second server.

The file on first server contains

files.php

```
while($file = mysql_fetch_array($files){
echo $file['file_name'];
echo '<a href="second_server.com/delete.php?file=' . $file['file_name'] . '">Delete</a>';
}
```

the file on second server contains

delete.php

```
if($_GET['file']){
if(file_exists($_GET['file']){
unlink($_GET['file'];
//file deleted !
}
```

No it's ok , but. I want done this job without redirect me or visitor to the second server

For example : ajax or curl or something like that. What is the best way to do that?

---

Edit.

The codes above is just tests. It's not my real files. Please help in the way to process delete request without redirect to second server php file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a simple file_get_contents is enough:

File on first server:

```
$result = file_get_contents('second-sercer.com/delete.php?file=text.txt&some_security_token=asd');
//From $result you will know what was the result on the other server
```

File on second server (delete.php);

```
if($_GET['some_security_token'] == "asd"){
  if(file_exists($_GET['file']){
    if(unlink($_GET['file'])){
       //File deleted we are cool
       echo 1;
    } else {
       //File deletion failed
       echo 0;
    }
  }else{
    //File don't exists
    echo -1;
  }
}else{
 //bad token
 echo -2;
}
```

So this way your first server on script level goes to the second server so you can check parameters before that. And the second server sends back error / success codes so you can handle them on first server:

```
1  - success
0  - failed deletion
-1 - file doesn't even exists
-2 - bad security token
```

I do not include a way to create a token that both of the servers know. You can hash the file name with some key value for start, but you have to make it expensive to guess. I just try to point out that you need this kind of security too to make it even safer. And you have to find out a way to protect file system from deleting files that important for second-server. For example you only let the deletion of files in some folder only.

You could use cURl too the same way for this. But always try to return info for the first-server.com about the process on the second-server.com

Comment: Thank you very much , i know that's is very dengirus way to delete files but i have ideas enough to protect my self , the problem was in the back request from the second server , and you have solved it , thank you very muck the_nakos

Answer (score 2):

`unset` unsets a **variable**, it doesn't have anything to do with files.
You're looking for [`unlink`](http://www.php.net/unlink).

BTW, you should do some serious validation on what you're going to `unlink`. Just blindly accepting *anything* in the URL can have serious consequences.

```
http://second_server.com/delete.php?file=delete.php
```

Comment: Hello deceze , i know .. the codes above is just tests ! i writed it now .. that's is not my real codes , please help in the way to proccess delete request without go to the second server

Comment: @Osama curl would be the default solution. Have you tried it?

Comment: @deceze, curl is unnecessary. file_get_contents runs a behind-the-scenes GET request to the url specified

Comment: Thank you deceze , curl / file_get_content is the best way for this job , problem fixed and thank you for your help -- about unset <- that's was just error in fastly writing .. sorry and thank you again

Comment: @Pranav file_get_contents and other file functions depend on a configuration directive that allows to transparently open URLs. This may be disabled and is hence not as portable as curl.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/?file=$file_on_second_server">Delete file</a>
<?php if ($foo = $_GET['file']) {
echo "<img src=\"http://second_server.com/delete.php?file=$foo\" style=\"display:none;\"><script>alert('deleted');</script>"; }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you marshall but i don't understand , anyway the problem fixed and thank you for your comment

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you want a security code or token or the like, so that unauthorised people do not delete files from your server.

```
while($file = mysql_fetch_array($files){
    echo $file['file_name'];
    echo '<a href="first_server.com/delete.php?file=' . $file['file_name'] . '">Delete</a>';
}
```

and in first_server.com/delete.php, put this:

```
file_get_contents('second-server.com/delete.php?file=' . $_GET['file'] . '&securitycode=thisisasecuritycode');
```